# Pronunciation of "du 11 septembre 2001"?

Tags: grammaire, prononciation, articles, nombres, élision

I would expect this to be pronounced "de l'onze septembre," despite being written with *du* instead of *de l'*.

Is that correct? Is it only written this way because it's written with numerals?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is always correct not to elide the word preceding both cardinals and ordinals in French so you can take it as a rule without risk.

> **Le un** et le deux sont sortis au loto, à **la une** du journal, **le huit** de cœur, le train **de onze** heures; c'est **le huitième** jour, **la onzième** de la classe, pour **la énième** fois.

Elided form might sometimes be observed but only to match (lazy) spoken French, :

> **l'huit** de cœur, le train **d'onze** heures, **l'huitième** jour, **l'onzième** de la classe, pour **l'enième** fois.

but never:

> <s>**L'un**</s> et le deux sont sortis au loto, à <s>**l'une**</s> du journal.

This doesn't apply to ***un*** and ***une*** when used as an article. In the opposite the elision is mandatory in that case, eg:

> **L'un** et l'autre. **L'une** ou l'autre.

This leads to both of these acceptable forms:

> Une pièce **d'un** Euro.
>
> Une pièce **de un** Euro.

There are no elisions with **Onze** when used in dates even in spoken French, so it is always:

> **du onze** septembre

and never

> <s>**de l'onze**</s> septembre.

---

Apart from numbers:

Note that ***de le*** might appear when ***le*** is a pronoun like in (thanks to Aerovistae to point it):

> Il me demande **de le** rencontrer.

***De le*** or ***de les*** are sometimes used for humorous purpose like in:

> [Le film **de les** Nuls](http://cdn-premiere.ladmedia.fr/var/premiere/storage/images/cinema/sorties-dvd/news-dvd/un-blu-ray-collector-pour-la-cite-de-la-peur-3842119/69908348-1-fre-FR/Un-blu-ray-collector-pour-La-cite-de-la-peur_portrait_w532.jpg).

It is also sometimes used by mistake before proper nouns while elision should be used:

> [La gare **de Le** Mans](http://ter-sncf.com/Region/pays_de_la_loire/gare/Le%20Mans.aspx)

should be

> La gare **du** Mans, like "Les 24 heures **du** Mans".

Comment: In spoken French we can sometimes contract `pour la énième fois` and say `pour l'enième fois` (only spoken).

Comment: @Apolo granted. Answer updated.

Comment: @Apolo Never heard that at all. Not that I'm objecting to what you're saying. Just to mention it could be region-based... I guess ?

Comment: My mom used to say "Je te le répète pour l'énième fois" =) However, I don't know if it is region based or simply wrong, I'm just saying that this can be heard sometimes.

Comment: In comparison, "à l'une du journal" is shocking

Comment: What is 'le huit de coeur'? This expression makes no sense to me. To the Googlemobile...;

Comment: OH.........duh.

Comment: Les derniers ajouts à ta réponse n'ont plus rien à voir avec les nombres. On ne sait pas vraiment ce que ça vient faire là.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ces ajouts répondent à l'évocation de la forme «de le» qui apparaît dans la question dans l'expression « de l'onze septembre » et aussi dans une réponse supprimée depuis.

Answer (score 7):

“*Onze*” is a weird word. You generally don’t elide the word that precedes it, as if it started with an [aspirated h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_h). Thus, you don’t say “*<strike>*l’onze septembre*</strike>” but “***le** onze septembre*”, and you both write and pronounce:

> du onze septembre

Because otherwise French would be no fun, there are of course exceptions to the “don’t elide in front of ’*onze*’” rule. You *can* (but do not have too) elide “de” and “que” in front of it. All the following sentences are correct.

> Il est près d’onze heures.
> Il est près de onze heures.
>
> Nous ne serons finalement qu’onze à table ce soir.
> Nous ne serons finalement que onze à table ce soir.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to object or to complete some propositions above.

*"Une pièce de un euro"*, though this can be heard, is surely a fault (*"d'un euro"* is correct).

Besides, the precision about proper names is uncomplete. Although you can't say :

*"la gare **de Le** Mans"*, (correct form is *"la gare **du** Mans"*)

still you must say:

"*La déclaration **de Le** Pen*" and not "*La déclaration du Pen*" :

**The rule is that proper names with the article "Le" must be contracted in "du" for places, but not for persons.**

*"L'un"* when *"un"* is a number and not an article, can effectively not be said, but you should have precised that *"un"*, in that case, is replaced by *"as"*, which is a synonym of *"un"* precisely made for this very case. (though most people have recently forgotten the precise meaning of *"l'as"*, thinking it means *"the best one"*: In fact, *"l'as"* doesn't mean *"the best one"*, but precisely *"the **number** one"*, so you must say: *"l'as et le deux sont sortis au loto"*, and not "*le un et le deux*", which is a fault, though often you can hear it.

Comment: I agree with *de Le Pen* vs *du Pen* but the statement about *de un euro* being a fault is incorrect. Most grammarians either recommend or rule *de un euro* vs *d'un euro*.