# How do you refer to certain denominations of bill and coin when asking for change?

Tags: vocabulaire, économie

I've found myself repeatedly needing to ask vendors for change in certain ways, and I realized I have no idea what words are used for this.

So far I've been getting away with this:

> *Vous avez de la monnaie ? (I hold out a €5 bill) Je voudrais **deux deux** et **un un***.

Of course I'm trying to say that I'd like two €2 coins and one €1 coin. People usually understand but it's not very smooth. In English that's exactly how you would say it though-- "Could I get two fives and a ten?" And then for coins we specify quarters, dimes, nickels, etc.

How is this done in French, with the euro?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We would not say "deux deux" or "un un" but

> J'aimerais *deux pièces de deux (euros) et une pièce de un*.

Ou

> Vous auriez de la monnaie sur 5 euros en pièces de un ?

if you want only 1€ coins. The same applies to banknotes.

> Vous auriez 2 billets de dix (euros) ? *(while showing a 20€ note)*

Edit after an interesting question:

In this particular case, "de un" is not contracted to "d'un". It can be contracted only if the noun "euro" follows:

> Une pièce de un.
>
> Une pièce de un euro.
>
> Une pièce d'un euro.
>
> **NOT** Une pièce d'un.

Comment: Why is it "de un" and not "d'un" ? It seems intuitively right but I couldn't put my finger on the grammatical rule at work here.

Comment: Good question! I do not know if there is a formal rule. Here, the contraction of "de un" into "d'un" is only possible if there is "euro" after: "des pièces de un", "des pièces de un euro" or "des pièces d'un euro". I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Aerovistae Elision (*d'un*) is mandatory when *un* is an **article** and forbidden (*de un*) when *un* is a **noun**. While it can be either in *une pièce d(e) un euro*, *un* can't be but a noun when alone so there is no elision. See http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/pronunciation-of-du-11-septembre-2001/9605#9605

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you. It seems obvious now.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add to SteffX's answer that in Québec, it is common to hear people say

> **deux deux** et **un un**

and even

> **deux deux** et **un une**.

"Une" comes from the other name given to "un dollar", which is "une piastre", sometimes written as "une piasse".